# Div background maintain at center in desktop and mobile view

Tags: css

Desktop View:

[image]

Mobile View:

[image]

How I can maintain the wood button at center?
Here is my current css for this button:

```
background-image: url("/assets/img/level/btn-strt.png");
font-family: Brushie;
cursor: pointer;
text-align: center;
color: #FFF;
width: 62%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
font-size: 18px;
height: 58px;
padding-top: 8px;
padding-left: 4px;
background-size: contain;
margin-top: 19px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Sample image for this button:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to set background position to center

add following to you css code

```
background-position: center;
```